# "A Day in the Life" vs "A Day in Life"

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article

There's a song by the Beatles *A Day in the Life*. I can't figure out why that *the* is there. Would it have been different if it had been written as *A Day in Life*?

Comment: Again, lyricists are not grammarians! They are too flexible!

Answer (score 4):

"A Day in the life of (X)" is a very common phrase (it doesn't even need to be a person):

> - ATL24 - A day in *the* life of the world's busiest airport
> - A Day in *the* Life of a Primary Care Doctor
> - A Day in *the* Life of Nike CEO Mark Parker

It could have been *A Day in Life*, but it adhered to this more ambiguous form here; from whose life was it a day? The man who "made the grade"? It doesn't really matter.

A Day in the Life (of X) is a common enough phrase, it could be anybody.

Comment: So it might have been a day in the life of John Lennon himself.

Comment: I would say, it starts us thinking first about the man's last day then to John's, and finally to anyone's.